# Roxygen: export imported function

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

I have an R package that was getting too big, so I split out a coherent chunk of it into a new package.

I want to provide a deprecation period for users who might have been relying on those functions, so I did this:

```
##' Blah blah function
##'
##' Deprecated - use `newpack::blah` instead.
##' @export
blah <- newpack::blah
```

One drawback is that `R CMD CHECK` warnings caused by `newpack::blah` are now warnings in this package:

```
Undocumented arguments in documentation object 'blah'
    ‘x’ ‘...’
```

What's a better way?

Answer (score 3):

Because of R's deep copying semantics, doing `blah <- newpack::blah` actually deeply copies the `newpack::blah` function into the current package, rather than just referring to it by name.

Instead of copying from one namespace to the other, import `blah` and re-export it:

```
##' Blah blah function
##'
##' Deprecated - use `newpack::blah` instead.
##' @importFrom newpack blah
##' @export blah
##' @name blah
NULL
```